# Rails CRUD operations using AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, rest

I'm developing a Rails app. I have generated all my resources using the `scaffold` generator, and now I'm working on javascript, on an AJAX function.

I saw that if I request `/entities/1.json`, it returns JSON data for the record with `id=1`, so I was wondering if it's possible to do other CRUD operations the same way with GET/POST http requests using routes like `/entities/new.json` or so, that is, make an AJAX request sending post data as JSON.

Can you guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can create records by posting JSON to your server. This is well covered in the Rails guides.

Comment: can you link me some rails guides where it's explained?

Comment: Start by reading [Working With Javascript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#dealing-with-ajax-events).

Answer (score 0):

As you saw, scaffolds generates proper url and code for both HTML and json, so sending a POST to create a resource should work without problems.

You can find more info in the Rails guides about [JavaScript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#dealing-with-ajax-events) and [JSON](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters)